# Why can't I access Server.app in Lion Server?

Tags: macos, osx-server

I can't access Server.app in my mac mini server, i don't know why.
The username and password are correct.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I found a problem, the servermgrd was not running, I was search in Active Monitor and no found it.

To resolve just run:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.servermgrd.plist
```

Comment: Nice catch - that would surely be an issue ;-)